# Symfony 4 - Use Algolia places with webpack encore

Tags: javascript, symfony, webpack, algolia

in my project symfony 4 I want to use Algolia places to select a city.

Using the CDN `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/places.js@1.17.0"></script>` it works good.

And I've :

```
    <script>
        const fixedOptions = {
        appId: '[id]',
        apiKey: '[key]',
        container: document.querySelector('#ordre_mission_lieu')
};

    const reconfigurableOptions = {
        language: 'fr', // Receives results in German
        countries: ['fr'], // Search in the United States of America and in the Russian Federation
        type: 'city', // Search only for cities names
        aroundLatLngViaIP: false // disable the extra search/boost around the source IP
    };
    const placesInstance = places(fixedOptions).configure(reconfigurableOptions);

    // dynamically reconfigure options
    placesInstance.configure({
        countries: ['fr'] // only search in the United States, the rest of the settings are unchanged: we're still searching for cities in German.
    })
</script>
```

But now I would like to use it with NPM.

In the documentation they show how to do: https://community.algolia.com/places/documentation.html#using-npm

So I executed this line to have the package `npm install places.js --save`
And since I'm using webpack-encore to manage my assets. In my app.js file, I did this:

```
const places = require("places.js");
```

And I removed the CDN link in my template.

Then I compiled my assets without problem and I reloaded my page. But Algolia is not taken into account. In the console, I get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: places is not defined
>       at new:481

At `const placesInstance = places(fixedOptions).configure(reconfigurableOptions);`

So what's the problem ? I I have however declared my `places` variable in my app.js to be able to use it

Comment: Did you tried to remove js extension? `const places = require("places");`

Comment: The problem is that the package name is "place.js" in the node_modules folder. So, I shouldn't edit this name. So in my app.js I've to require("places.js"), and not "places"

Comment: --edit-- Your comment is right, my bad !

Comment: Yes, if i write ```require("places")``` I've an error ^^

Comment: Nobody to help me ? :(

Comment: did you try to put your script in app.js just after the require?

Comment: I can not do that because my app.js contains all my imports and it is loaded on all my templates. It would mean that in all my templates, I will use this script, and so it would be a bug because the script must apply to a field

Comment: Problem resolved. I had to write this ```global.places = places;```